# Need good reasons to move from Perforce to git - REALLY good reasons

Tags: git, perforce

I work in a company with dev teams in both US and Europe. Each facility currently uses Perforce and we're planning to build new systems jointly. Being a distributed team, I'm keen that we move to git or Mercurial, but m'colleagues are wary. They like Perforce, and can't see any benefits of moving to a DVCS.

Gotta admit I'm struggling to come up with good reasons that convince. A fast line between the 2 facilities means we can use a central Perforce repo, or clone one for each facility.

A worry that has arisen is that there would not be one master repo: a developer would never know if the code he's just checked out is up to date - suppose someone else is updating same file?

Yes I'm a git/Mercurial noob. Can anyone help me out with hard-to-argue-against reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to move to git if you do not know why you want to move to git?  =O

Comment: Do you have enough muscle to carry your vision through? perhaps this belongs to career.SE (j/k). About the master repo, you can use one centralized server and refer to that as `the` master repo.

Comment: I've got the 'muscle' but I want to take the team with me. Better that than just force it through eh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not seem to be about git/mercurial so much as centralized versus distributed VCS:

1. Distributed VCS - pros

   - multiple copies of source; if server goes down, code is available from multiple workstations
   - local copies means that updates tend to be smaller and less network-intensive
2. Distributed VCS - cons

   - synchonizing changes; if you have a high rate of checkin and multiple staff working on same modules you need to have a *very* clear protocol for push/pull/merge
3. Centralized VCS - pros

   - one place for the code - you know which repository is or should be canonical
4. Centralized VCS - cons

   - one place for the code - server unavailability means developers are unable to branch/version for long without issues

Comment: "Your question does not seem to be about git/mercurial so much as centralized versus distributed VCS" - yes correct! Thanks for your answer! Your third bullet is of particular interest to me, that's the tough management issue.

Comment: then I recommend you do the time-honored tradition of starting the infection small. Every IT org has helper apps - minor loaders, example code, etc. Start a DVCS repository for the non-critical stuff to "get it out of the way" of your big-boy main products. Let people get experience with DVCS without threatening the main mission, and after a while the leap will not seem so large (plus you'll have more experience and decide maybe it's not such a good idea after all).

Comment: Also - this doesn't have to be an either-or. There are lots of centralized DVCS repositories (e.g. GitHub). If you create a bare repo on the central server and push into it, you have one central place for backups, builds, etc but still enjoy the distributed benefits.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know of any reasons to switch, why do you want to switch?

While people can give you features of git they like that perforce lacks - "local repository means faster history!", "I can't live without git bisect", "perforce has no stash so it's hard to checkin discrete units!"... nobody will be able to tell you what git does better than perforce for your company.

So ask yourself this: "What does my department need that perforce lacks?" and "What could we do better without some limitation that perforce is enforcing?".  Once you answer those questions, see if git can help.  At the end of asking the real questions, the "hard to argue against reasons" will be in your hands, and apply to your actual coworkers.

Comment: That's part of my reason for asking the question...

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase my question, something like: can anyone think of any scenarios where moving from a centralised VCS to a distributed one would be sensible? That's probably my 'real' question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, "Can anyone think of any scenarios where moving from a centralised VCS to a distributed one would be sensible?" Yes, I can:

- Your development teams are very loosely coupled. They have independent schedules, management, standards, etc. They are so independent that a CVCS is just bureaucratic red tape for them.
- The development they do is not subject to audits or compliance standards. Having no central record of who did what when will not be a problem for your company.